# What does "I Ship Nalu" mean?

Tags: fairy-tail, terminology

Just wondering on this, but is this some type of new vocab in Fairy Tail or something, Long story short: I have seen a lot of comments on Facebook and YouTube like "Do you ship Nalu" and "I ship Nalu". What does this mean though?

[image]

Comment: `NaLu` seems to be a [portmanteau](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portmanteau) of Natsu and Lucy (note the casing). Guess these are about wanting to see them as an item. Look completely fan based though.

Comment: hmmmm you might want to add the `terminology` tag to this

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Wait, I know what it is now based on Oded's comment. NaLu is the term fans use for wanting Lucy + Natsu to get together and based off Wikipedia it is safe to say that this is a Portmanteau.

Definition:

> A combination of two (or more) words or morphemes, and their
>   definitions, into one new word.

Thanks, Oded. :)

Comment: Not sure where "I ship" comes from though...

Comment: Aaaand... http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=ship

Comment: @robin fair point. shouldnt post comments when sleepy ;p

Answer (score 5):

"To ship" or "shipping," in fan communities is the act or pairing characters within a series together, in a romantic relationship. It's a fairly commonly used term through-out the internet, especially on fan-sites.

Often times, a "ship" (fan-based pairing) is usually called by a combination of their names. Some communities even use a term, "shipper", to refer to people who consistently "ship" a certain type of pairing ("fujoshi-shippers" being those who always ship male homosexual pairings and so one)

As has already been pointed out, "NaLu" would be the name of the "ship" of Natsu and Lucy, and people who say "I ship NaLu" basically are the part of the fandom that supports the idea of a relationship between the two.

Answer (score 2):

A ship is a couple that you want to be together. Ships like Jerza, (Jellal and Erza), Gruvia, (Gray and Juvia), and Nalu (Natsu and Lucy), are all fictitious couples that fans choose. Shipping is like to make a couple out of two people, and you can make a name. Jerza, Nalu, are all ship names. Therefore, shipping Nalu basically means that you want Natsu and Lucy to be together.